# How to prove set inclusion in a group with a prime cardinality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

Given the question:

If $H,\,K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, and $\lvert H\rvert$ is a prime number, show that either $H\subseteq K$ or $H\cap K=\{1\}$.

I tried solving it as follows:

Assume $K\subset H$ then $K$ is a group and a subset of $H$, so $K$ is a subgroup of $K$.

Then by Lagrange's theorem, $|K|\mid |H|$, yet $|H|$ is a prime number so $|K|=1$. Since $K$ is a group it must contain the identity so $K=\{1\}$.

Assume $K \not \subset H$, then either $H \subseteq K$ or $\exists k \in K$ and $\exists h \in H$ such that $k \notin H$ and $h \notin K$.

Assume the second, then we have that, since $H \subseteq G$ and $K \subseteq G$ then $kh = z$ for some $z \in G$.

If $z \in H$ we have $k = zh^{-1}$ and since $h,h^{-1} \in H$ and $H$ is a group, then $k \in H$.

Which is a contradiction.

For the same argument $z \notin K$.

However all this lets me conclude is that $z \notin K$ and $z \notin H$

Which isn't particularily useful. I wonder if there is a hint as to what I could try to finalize the proof. Maybe a property of groups I skipped.

Comment: Do you have Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: As inn do I have it open or whether I can use it?

Comment: By the way, as a general rule in these sorts of questions you should probably try to push LaGrange's Theorem really hard to try not to get so muddled in the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose

$H \cap K \ne \{ e \}, \tag 1$

where $e \in G$ is the identity element. Then

$\exists \; e \ne h \in H \cap K; \tag 2$

since $\vert H \vert = p$ is prime, $H$ is a cyclic group of order $p$ and hence is generated by any non-identity element; thus we may write

$H = \langle h \rangle; \tag 3$

now since $h \in K$, and $K$ being a subgroup is closed under the group operation, every power $h^n$ of $h$ is in $K$; thus

$H = \langle h \rangle \subset K; \tag 4$

***Note Added in Edit, 27 February 2018 11:23 PM PST:***

Let $\vert H \vert = p$, a prime.  Let $e \ne h \in H$ and consider the sequence of powers of $h$:

$h^1 = h,\; h^2,\; h^3, \; \ldots, h^p; \tag 5$

if all the entries in this list are distinct, then since $\vert H \vert = p$, every element of $H$ occurs precisely once; thus we must have $h^p = e$; if not then $h^m = e$ for some $m$, $1 \le m < p$; but then $h = he = hh^m = h^{m + 1}$ and so $h$ occurs at least twice in the list; hence $h^p = e$; since the list elements are assumed distinct, we have $H = \langle h \rangle$, the cyclic group generated by $h$.  If the list entries are *not* distinct, then we must have $h^j = h^k$ for some $1 \le j < k \le p$; then 
$h^{k - j} = e$ and the elements

$h = h^1, \; h^2, \ldots, h^{k - j} = e \tag 6$

form a subgroup $H'$ of $H$; then by LaGrange's theorem, $\vert H' \vert \mid \vert H \vert$; since $\vert H \vert = p$ is prime, $\vert H' \vert = 1$ or  $\vert H' \vert = p$; since $h \ne e$ we cannot have $\vert H' \vert = 1$, so $\vert H' \vert = p$; but this is impossible since the list (6) contains at most $p - 1$ entries.  Therefore this assumption that the elements of the list (5) are not distinct may be ruled out.

If $x \in H$ with $x^2 = e$, then $\{1, x \}$ forms a subgroup of $H$ order $2$; again by LaGrange's theorem, $2 \mid p$.  Since $p$ is prime, we must thus have $p = 2$ and $H = \langle x \rangle = \{ 1, x \}$.

***End of Note.***

Comment: "is a cyclic group of order p and hence is generated by any non-identity element"

Why is that the case? why can't I have all elements be their own inverses such that $x^2=e$ for all $x \in H$?

Comment: Give me a few and I'll answer you!  Cheers!

Comment: I still can't understand why that must be the case :p

Comment: I edited my answer to address the questions you asked in the comments.  Hope this helps!  Cheers!

Comment: @Makogan If you have a group of prime order $p>2$, you will not be able to find any element of order $2$. All the (non-identity) elements will be of order $p$, and they will all generate the whole group.

Comment: Seems much more complicated than needed. $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$, which has prime order. Thus by Lagrange's theorem either $H \cap K = \{1\}$ or $H \cap K = H$ which implies $H \subseteq K$.

Comment: @JohnColeman:  Yes, you may be right.  I was writing rapidly to respond to Makogen's questions and it was late; I should have gone to bed an answered him in the morning!

Answer (score 4):

Take any non-identity element $h \in H$ and let $|H|=p$. The order of $h$ divides $p$ (why?), and because $p$ is prime and $|h|>1$ we have $|h|=p$; thus $H= \left< h \right>$ (why?). Either $H\cap K = \{1 \}$ or $H\cap K \not = \{1 \}$. If the first is true, we are done. If the second is true, then $K$ contains a non-identity element $h \in H$ which will generate all of $H$ inside $K$, so $H \subseteq K$.

Comment: why is the order of $h$ necessarily $p$? what about having a subgroup where every element is it's own inverse?  then $ x^2=1$ so $|x|=2$

Comment: $\langle h \rangle$ is a subgroup of $H$ and its order is precisely $|h|$. Apply Lagrange again.

Comment: @Makogan Then that subgroup would definitely contain only $x$ and the identity. The set $\left < h \right > = \{h^0, h^1, h^2, ..., h^n \}$ is a subgroup of $H$ so it's order divides $|H|$, which is a prime. Thus  $\left < h \right >$ either has order $1$ or $p$, and since $h$ is not the identity, it has order $>1$, thus $p$.

Answer (score 2):

I would take an even easier approach. Take $H\cap K$. Since $H$ and $K$ are both subgroups $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$. Then $|H\cap K|$ divides $|H|$ and so is either $1$ or $p$. If it's $1$ it must be $e$ if it's $p$ then all of $H=H\cap K\subseteq K$. We are using the fact that $p$ is finite in the second part.